# HTML5 web workers and concurrency

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I currently have 2 web workers setup like this:

```
gpsThread = new Worker("js/workers/gpsd_poll.js");
gpsStarted = true;

gpsThread.onmessage = function(event) {
    if (event.data !== "") {
         do lots of stuff here.....
    }
}

netThread = new Worker("js/workers/net_poll.js");
netStarted = true;

netThread.onmessage = function(event) {
    if (event.data !== "") {
         do lots of stuff here.....
    }
}
```

When gpsThread receives a message and processing, netThread must wait until gpsThread has completed before it begins its callback.

Is there anyway to make them run 'concurrently'? I have tried nesting them together like this:

```
gpsThread = new Worker("js/workers/gpsd_poll.js");
gpsStarted = true;

netThread = new Worker("js/workers/net_poll.js");
netStarted = true;

gpsThread.onmessage = function(event) {
    netThread.onmessage = function(event) {
        if (event.data !== "") {
             do lots of stuff here.....
        }
    }

    if (event.data !== "") {
         do lots of stuff here.....
    }
}
```

Comment: Web workers *do* run concurrently, there's no way to prevent that. They can only communicate via asynchronous events. As usual, you cannot "wait" unless you use a callback.

Comment: Please show us at least the part where you are sending messages to your workers.

Comment: I think you mean "consecutively" since, as @Bergi mentioned, they do run "concurrently"

Comment: you could have them both push into a shared worker since you're not getting any MP speedup by queuing anyway

Comment: Maybe you could post some sort of pseudocode/flow diagram that shows the order of events / flow of work or data, in order to clarify how you would like the code to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible for a concurrent read/write read/write collision in JavaScript in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884186/is-it-possible-for-a-concurrent-read-write-read-write-collision-in-javascript-in)