# Vue data value not updating for in function use

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

So i'm trying to lazy load articles with infinite scrolling, with inertia-vue and axios, backend is laravel 6.0. Since I don't want to do unnecessary request i'm giving over the total amount of articles to the component. I'm also tracking the amount of already loaded articles in the component data.

```
props: {
    article_count: Number,
   },
data: function () {
    return {
        loaded: 0,
        scrolledToBottom: false,
        articles: [],
    }
},
```

The articles that are loaded are all being put into `articles`, and `scrolledToBottom` keeps track if the user has scrolled to the bottom. I have already checked if `this` refers to the vue component and has the data properties, which it does.

```
methods: {
    load: function (nextToLoad) {
        for (let i = nextToLoad; i < nextToLoad + 10; i++){
            if (this.loaded <= this.article_count){
                this.$axios.get(route('api_single_article', i))
                    .then(response => {
                        if (response.status == 200 && response.data != null) {
                            console.log(this.loaded);
                            this.articles.push(response.data);
                        }
                        this.loaded++;
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        if (error.response.status != 404) {
                            console.log(error);
                            console.log(this.loaded);
                            this.loaded++;
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
        console.log(this.loaded);
    },
    scroll: function () {
        window.onscroll = () => {
            let bottomOfWindow = document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight === document.documentElement.offsetHeight;

            if (bottomOfWindow) {
                this.load(this.loaded + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The weird part is, that if i log `this.loaded` in the response / error arrow function it always returns 0. If i do it outside the response it also returns 0, but if i log `this` the `loaded` property has the supposed value after the loop has ran through, despite it being logged every time the loop is run. I have already showed this to a friend and he also couldn't fix it. The behaviour just seems weird to me and i don't know how else i should do, since i'm very inexperienced with vue.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: why is `this.$axios`, it should be just `axios` and is this `route('api_single_article', i)` laravel stuff!!

Comment: since axios by default somehow didn't work so i added it with ```Vue.prototype.$axios = axios;``` and with https://github.com/tightenco/ziggy you can pass your laravel routes to js

Comment: for test purpose that axios is make `request` and get a `response`,try with hard coded route url e.g: `'api/article/'+i`

Comment: I already tested that, Delena Malan's tip has lead me to the solution, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a concurrency thing. Remember that the axios call is asynchronous so the loop will continue before the responses have been received.

<s>So it could be the many responses are received at the same time and that `loaded` is then still 0 at that point.</s> Looks like this won't be the case. [Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27884477/3486675) JavaScript will process callbacks one after the other.

I'm not sure how JavaScript handles concurrent increments though so I can't exactly explain how that plays into effect here.

From your implementation, it looks like you'd want to turn the `load` function into an asynchronous function (using the `async`) keyword and then use the `await` before the axios call to ensure that you have received a response before making another request.

For interest's sake, maybe have a look at your network tab and count how many requests are being made. I suspect there will be more requests made than `this.article_count`.

Comment: Yeah there are 10 requests being made at the same time. After I added the async await and fixed a logic error ```if (this.loaded < this.article_count``` instead of ```if (this.loaded <= this.article_count``` it works properly now. Thanks a lot :)